# Create multiband raster from a single band raster with fields

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, raster, grass-gis, multi-band

I have a raster which has a single band containing what is effectively a lookup code. When I open the raster in ArcMap and open the attribute table I can see several fields which I guess come from the accompanying `.vat.dbf` file. There is also a `.csv` file for looking up the field values.

I want to output a multiband raster where the bands are formed from a selection of the fields found in the input raster. So effectively converting some of the fields to bands.

I know that this could be achieved by first creating serval single-band rasters using the `Lookup` function inside the **RasterCalculator** to extract each required field and the use the **Composite Bands** tool to produce the desired output. However, the dataset is fairly large so this would take too long, can anyone suggest a more efficient way?

Any solution using GDAL, GRASS, QGIS or ArcGIS (with SA Extension) is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- QGIS is out, it doesn't support raster attribute tables at all.
- I don't know about GRASS.
- GDAL would require you to (manually or in python code) handcraft VRTs with lookup tables from the attribute table fields for each "band", then composite the VRTs.
- In ArcGIS, you can only use `Lookup` and `Composite Bands`. However, look at the versions of those functions for on the fly processing i.e [raster functions](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/data/imagery/list-of-raster-functions.htm), not the spatial analyst map algebra functions.

You could build a raster function template to do the lookup and composite in one go (kind of like model builder). You then have to save the custom function and apply it.

i.e

[image]